# tinymce plugin & tinymce.init() on different domain

Tags: dns, tinymce, cross-domain

How can i run tinymce cross-domain?
tinymce.js, tiny_mce_popup.js & its plugin are located on a server, while tinymce.init() is initialised on index.html at local file system. Local file system can access all paths from server, but tiny_mce_popup.js seems to be not working.

It was all working when index.html & all plugin set of tinymce was located at localhost,i.e. my domain was localhost.

Any idea/advice/suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the document.domain is the same in all frames (mainwindow and tinymce iframe)!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running on version 3,

As per documentation [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/howto/TinyMCE3x@How-to_load_TinyMCE_crossdomain/) TinyMCE cannot be run crossdomain, only cross-subdomain.

If you want to run it cross-subdomain, you should set

```
document.domain = example.com
```

Once this is done, you can have your tinymce files hosted on a CDN subdomain, for example, and use it in your website.